# string.Compare behavior

Tags: .net, string, localization, string-comparison

How this can be ? (This is taken from the immediate window in VS2008)

```
?string.Compare("-", "+")
-1
?string.Compare("-0", "+0")
1
```

Answer (score 8):

From the remarks on [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The comparison uses the current culture to obtain culture-specific information such as casing rules and the alphabetic order of individual characters. For example, a culture could specify that certain combinations of characters be treated as a single character, or uppercase and lowercase characters be compared in a particular way, **or that the sorting order of a character depends on the characters that precede or follow it**.

Comment: Hey Johannes,  i saw that. But my machine is an XP English setup. And + and - are standard ascii characters below 127.

I don't see how 0 can affect their relative order in my current culture.

Comment: While sometimes counter-intuitive, sophisticated string comparison functions such as `String.Compare` here can have niceties such as ordering "Strasse" near "Straße", "école" near "ecole" and "file9.txt" near "file10.txt".

Comment: @Juan the latter example "file9.txt" before "file10.txt" is desirable even in an English setup, and probably you are somehow falling in this case as soon as you add the zeroes.

Comment: Juan: Just because historically there was paid little special attention to collation in English doesn't mean that there *aren't* cases where an English locale might differ from pure ASCII or codepoint sort order. It's not like English is a language which doesn't need any special rules on computers.

Comment: Tank you all. 

The original problem is that i have to sort a list using a combination
of an int and a string field. 

To resolve that i've built a string that combines both trying to 
folow a string order.

I've resolved that with an offset to the int value so all values are positive.

As additional information c++ wcscmp behaves ok in my machine. 

Thank you again

Comment: C++ is not .NET. They follow different standards, so don't expect them to sort the same :-)

Comment: Yea, i know. Well, if i find the sorting rules somewhere or why this behaves this way, i'll post it here.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

The C# manual writes:

> The comparison uses the current
>   culture to obtain culture-specific
>   information such as casing rules and
>   the alphabetic order of individual
>   characters. For example, a culture
>   could specify that certain
>   combinations of characters be treated
>   as a single character, or uppercase
>   and lowercase characters be compared
>   in a particular way, or that the
>   sorting order of a character depends
>   on the characters that precede or
>   follow it.
>
> The comparison is performed using word
>   sort rules. For more information about
>   word, string, and ordinal sorts, see
>   [System.Globalization.CompareOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx).