# String.Compare answer changes as chracters are added to the end of the string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a simple application that attempts to compare 2 strings using String.Compare.  I have run into a situation where the answer changes as I add more values to each string.

Take these 2 strings:

```
---a
--1S
```

String.Compare shows the following results when comparing a growing number of values in the string:

```
String.Compare
   -:   -   0
  --:  --   0
 ---: --1  -1
---a:--1S   1
```

Why does it change its answer?  It should remain -1 once it gets to the 3rd position, regardless of the additional values added to the string.

On the other hand `String.CompareOrdinal` agrees with this and remains < 0 for all string lengths.

Here is a sample program that demonstrates these results.

```
using System;

namespace TestFileMerge
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string value1 = "---a";
            const string value2 = "--1S";
            Console.WriteLine("String.Compare");
            for (int i = 1; i <= value1.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    @"{0}:{1} {2}", 
                    value1.Substring(0, i).PadLeft(value2.Length), 
                    value2.Substring(0, i).PadLeft(value2.Length), 
                    String.Compare(
                        value1.Substring(0, i), 
                        value2.Substring(0, i),
                        false
                    ).ToString().PadLeft(3));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("String.Compare -- ignore case");
            for (int i = 1; i <= value1.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    @"{0}:{1} {2}", 
                    value1.Substring(0, i).PadLeft(value2.Length), 
                    value2.Substring(0, i).PadLeft(value2.Length), 
                    String.Compare(
                        value1.Substring(0, i), 
                        value2.Substring(0, i),
                        true
                    ).ToString().PadLeft(3));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("String.CompareOrdinal");
            for (int i = 1; i <= value1.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine
                    (@"{0}:{1} {2}", 
                    value1.Substring(0, i).PadLeft(value2.Length), 
                    value2.Substring(0, i).PadLeft(value2.Length), 
                    String.CompareOrdinal(
                        value1.Substring(0, i), 
                        value2.Substring(0, i)
                    ).ToString().PadLeft(3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
String.Compare
   -:   -   0
  --:  --   0
 ---: --1  -1
---a:--1S   1
String.Compare -- ignore case
   -:   -   0
  --:  --   0
 ---: --1  -1
---a:--1S   1
String.CompareOrdinal
   -:   -   0
  --:  --   0
 ---: --1  -4
---a:--1S  -4
```

Comment: What is the `CultureInfo` of the current thread?

Comment: This question shows a good reason to always specify the StringComparison style.

Comment: I think this is pretty interesting. Since I don't know your culture, I tried with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, and it reproduces with that. The fourth character seems less important. For example `String.Compare("---", "--1")` returns `-1`, while `String.Compare("---x", "--1x")` returns positive `1`. (At least with invariant culture, like I said.)

Comment: At least the zeros agree.   My guess is that you are getting a numeric comparison up until it sees a letter for the first two.  Put letter as the first char to test.

Comment: After digging into the `StringComparison` idea I found that `String.Compare` also takes a `CompareOptions` Enumeration.  One of the options is `StringSort`.  "Indicates that the string comparison must use the string sort algorithm. In a string sort, the hyphen and the apostrophe, as well as other nonalphanumeric symbols, come before alphanumeric characters."  It would seem that by default the comparison treats the -'s as > alphanumeric's.

Comment: How does that explain the inconsistent results?  If -- are treated consistently then the answer should not change.   I think it is switching from numeric to alphenumeric and that option just makes alplaynumeric behave like numeric.

Comment: The `String.Compare` documentation says it may treat repeated characters as one based upon cultural settings, I suspect the -'s are collapsed into 1 character in the default comparison.  The full explanation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx).

Comment: @usr But even when you specify that, the same behavior shows up. See last part of my answer. To me, this is unusual.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not passing an `CultureInfo`, the comparison for `String.Compare` will be based on the current thread culture, which may have different comparison rules than you expect. `String.CompareOrdinal` only compares code points, without taking culture into account.

In other words, try using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxc48dt.aspx) with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

This is the reason for the different comparisons.

Comment: Can you provide more insight into how I provide the `IFormatProvider` to the `String.Compare` to get the results I expect?  I do not see it as a possible overload input.

Comment: Ouch, it actually seems like the overload takes the concrete class `CultureInfo` and not the `IFormatProvider` interface. A bit odd, since the .NET API's almost always uses `IFormatProvider`, but not this one. I updated the answer.

Comment: This overload results in the same results as using `String.CompareOrdinal` which is acceptable, but I was still left wondering why the `String.Compare` did not work as expected.  Turns out I needed to specify the `CompareOptions.StringSort` parameter to get the desired results.

Comment: But trying the overload you specify doesn't change a thing! See my answer. There's something strange about this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `String.Compare` method to treat non alphanumeric values as I expected I needed to provide the `CultureInfo` as well as a `ComparOptions` `Enum` value.

Rewriting the first method in the questions example as follows produces the desired results:

```
String.Compare(
    value1.Substring(0, i), 
    value2.Substring(0, i),
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    CompareOptions.StringSort
}
```

The `CompareOptions.StringSort` "Indicates that the string comparison must use the string sort algorithm. In a string sort, the hyphen and the apostrophe, as well as other nonalphanumeric symbols, come before alphanumeric characters."

Thanks to everyone that pointed me down the `CultureInfo` path that led to this `Enum`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a weird behavior. Consider the following

```
static void Test()
{
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        const string a = "-";
        const string b = "1";

        Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(a, b));                  // -1
        Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(a + "x", b + "x"));      // +1
}
```

Why does concatenating **on the right** with the same constant `"x"` reverse the order of the strings? This is in the invariant culture, as you see.

According to the invariant culture and the `String.Compare(String, String)` overload, the following list of strings is sorted ascendingly:

```
""
"-"
"--"
"1"
"1-"
"-1"
"11"
"1x"
"1y"
"x"
"x-"
"-x"
"x1"
"xx"
"xy"
"y"
"y-"
"-y"
"y1"
"yx"
"yy"
```

I couldn't find a violation of transitivity. But it does seem strange if you read the left-most "column" of characters above that the minuses appear so late.

**Addition:** The first example again for those who insist on using verbose overloads:

```
String.Compare("-", "1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);   // -1
String.Compare("-x", "1x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase); // +1
```

(Also works with e.g. `CompareOptions.None`.) See the proposition of the title of this thread. Appending to the strings reverses their order. Why?

**New addition:** It seems that without specifying ordinal comparison or `CompareOptions.StringSort`, the algorithm is: First remove all hyphens (`-`) from both strings. If one is greater than the other after that, return that answer. (Otherwise, consider the hyphens again...) With `"---"` and `"--1"`, remove hyphens to get `""` and `"1"`. They still differ, and the first one is least. Return minus one. However, with `"---a"` and `"--1S"`, the call compares `"a"` and `"1S"`, now the first is greatest, and it returns plus one.

By the way, this question is very similar: [string.Compare behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873701/)

Answer (score -1):

just to clarify you know the answer is on the right, right?

it'll just be less or more than 0 if it doesn't compare, and 0 if it does

Comment: That's not the point of the question. The question is asking why it changes sign.